# Run-time error '13': Type mismatch on VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I'm using the following code in a project that I'm working on:

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Technician Report Summary").Range("G2:I8561").ClearContents
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    n = Range("C:C").Cells.Count
    i = Cells(n, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Source = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(n, "E"))
    Set Target = Range("G2:I2")

    For i = 2 To n
        If Source.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Not Used" And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Source.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
            Source.Rows(i).Copy
            Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Set Target = Target.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

When I run the code it appears to operate appropriately, it copies a list of filtered values following the criteria set in the code to another spot in the same worksheet. The problem is that I also get the following error:

> Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

What have I got wrong? I think that I've made some kind of error in declaring the variables or something to that effect, but I'm not familiar enough with VBA to pinpoint quite what the problem is.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Sorry for not being clear.

I have a set of values in the worksheet 'Technician Report Summary' that occupies the range C2:E8561. There's some erroneous values that I want to have filtered out and copied, these are "Not Used" and '#N/A' errors. The code above copies the values and then pastes them next to the original, unfiltered set of values with the instances of "Not Used" and '#N/A' removed in columns G, H, and I.

No line is highlighted as being the problem when I run it, the error dialog just pops up and when I hit "OK" nothing is highlighted.

EDIT 2:

I made the change that @KFitchter suggest and now it seems to lock-up. I hit the escape key and the following line was highlighted:

```
If Source.Cells(i, 1).Text <> "Not Used" And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Source.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
```

EDIT 3:

Just thought of something else that could be messing with it. The values in columns C,D and E are actually functions pulling values from elsewhere in the workbook. Here's an example of one of those functions.

> =INDEX('RAW DATA'!$A:$A,$B2)

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Comment: side note: `Set Source = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(n, "E"))` does not qualify which sheet the `range` or `cells` are being drawn from. You need to clarify that for this to work properly/work without unexpected future errors.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  For one (as @KFichter mentions) you haven't told us the error line.  Secondly, you haven't told us what the code is supposed to do for proper evaluation.

Comment: Does Cells() take letters as arguments? Edit: Indeed it does, I genuinely did not know that.

Comment: @KFichter - yes, the second argument can be either numeric or a column letter

Comment: The issue might be `Source.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "Not Used"` try using `Source.Cells(i, 1).Text <> "Not Used"` instead

Comment: Try stepping through the project (F8) and let us know where the code fails

Comment: @KFichter I did as you said and made an edit to my original post. It seems to break down at the start of the If.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm not exactly sure what the problem is.

I modified your code just a tiny bit (using my original guess) to:

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Worksheets("Technician Report Summary").Range("G2:I8561").ClearContents
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long
    n = Range("C:C").Cells.Count
    i = Cells(n, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Set Source = Range(Cells(1, "C"), Cells(n, "E"))
    Set Target = Range("G2:I2")

    For i = 2 To n
        If Source.Cells(i, 1).Text <> "Not Used" And Not Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(Source.Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
            Source.Rows(i).Copy
            Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            Set Target = Target.Offset(1)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Where the only real difference is "Value" to "Text". I'm not getting any errors. The only thing is that it's taking a long while to do what it's supposed to do because there are so many lines.

**Now...** I would suggest maybe doing what you're doing a little differently.

```
Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Worksheets("Technician Report Summary").Range("G2:I8561").ClearContents

    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Dim n As Long

    ActiveSheet.Range("C:E").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= _
        Array("<>#N/A", "<>Not Used"), Operator:=xlAnd
    ActiveSheet.Range("C:E").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "<>#N/A", Operator:=xlAnd

    n = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Source = Range("C2:E" & n).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Set Target = Range("G2")

    Source.Copy
    Target.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Range("C:E").AutoFilter
End Sub
```

This basically does what you were trying to do, but with autofilter. It's much faster than looping through every single cell and does the same thing in the end. I hope that helps...

Comment: The same sort of thing happens, it locks up and when I hit the escape key to get out of it the first line of the If is highlighted.

Comment: Could you possibly throw together some sample (non sensitive) data that throws the error so I can play with the VBA? I made some up based on the description you gave, but it's working.

Comment: OK, I've done as you suggested. Here's a link for it in Google Drive: [Tech Report - Troubleshoot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_fZnVjXU9YAUlVQOTdNSHRrdG8).

Comment: @nickelcap I basically updated everything using a faster method. I hope that does what you need it to do.

Comment: Thank you very much! It's working great now, but as you said the first method is much slower. I've decided to use the second method you suggested since it does what I want and it's much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Start by specifying the parent of all of your range and cell references.

Do not combine error checking with other string comparisons or boolean checks. Check for an error first and then process other boolean checks on a new code line.

The line `n = .Range("C:C").Cells.Count` puts 1,048,576 into *n*. Do you really want `Set src = .Range("C1:E1048576)` and `For i = 2 To 1048576` ?

Direct text comparisons are usually case-sensitive.

Use direct value transfer over Copy, Paste Special, Values whenever possible.

Put all of those points together as:

```
Sub test()
    Dim src As Range, trgt As Range, nas As Range
    Dim n As Long, i As Long, bERR As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Worksheets("Technician Report Summary")
        .Range("G2:I8561").ClearContents
        n = .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Set src = .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(n, "E"))
        Set trgt = .Range("G2:I2")
    End With

    For i = 2 To n
        If Not IsError(src.Cells(i, 3)) Then
            Debug.Print src.Cells(i, 3).Text
            If LCase(src.Cells(i, 1).Value2) <> "not used" Then
                trgt = src.Rows(i).Value
                Set trgt = trgt.Offset(1)
            End If
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

That should be enough to get you working.